# How to properly use PHP5 semaphores?

Tags: php, semaphore

I have this function that tries to read some values from cache. But if value does not exists it should call alternative source API and save new value into the cache. However, server is very overloaded and almost each time when value does not exists more then one requests are created (a lot of API calls) and each of them will store new vale into cache. However, what I want is to be able to call API many times, but only one process/request to be able to store it in cache:

```
function fetch_cache($key, $alternativeSource) {
    $redis = new Redis();
    $redis->pconnect(ENV_REDIS_HOST);
    $value = $redis->get($key);

    if( $value === NULL ) {
        $value = file_get_contents($alternativeSource);

        // here goes part that I need help with
        $semaphore = sem_get(6000, 1); // does this need to be called each time this function is called?
        if( $semaphore === FALSE ) {
            // This means I have failed to create semaphore?
        }

        if( sem_aquire($semaphore, true) ) {
            // we have aquired semaphore so here
            $redis->set($key, $value);
            sem_release($semaphore); // releasing lock
        }

        // This must be call because I have called sem_get()?
        sem_remove($semaphore);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Is this proper use of semaphore in PHP5?

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to use transactions in redis to set the keys?  i.e. start a transaction in redis - check if key isn't set - if not set and return it else return it.  Similar effect but keeps the PHP simple?

Comment: That is actually good proposal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short answer

1. You don't need to create and remove semaphores within the `fetch_cache` function. Put `sem_get()` into an initialization method (such as `__construct`).
2. You should remove semaphores with `sem_remove()`, but in a cleanup method (such as `__destruct`). Or, you might want to keep them even longer - depends on the logic of your application.
3. Use `sem_acquire()` to acquire locks, and `sem_release()` to release them.

## Description

### `sem_get()`

Creates a set of [three](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/16160386982a86e6ec7969c6c89707d38228f19e/ext/sysvsem/sysvsem.c#L115) semaphores.

The underlying C function `semget` is *not atomic*. There is a possibility of [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when two processes trying to call `semget`. Therefore, `semget` should be called in some initialization process. The PHP extension overcomes this issue by means of three semaphores:

*Semaphore 0 a.k.a. `SYSVSEM_SEM`*

Is initialized to `sem_get`'s `$max_acquire` and decremented as processes acquires it.

The first process that called `sem_get` fetches the value of `SYSVSEM_USAGE`semaphore (see below). For the first process, it equals to `1`, because the extension [sets it to `1`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/16160386982a86e6ec7969c6c89707d38228f19e/ext/sysvsem/sysvsem.c#L239) with atomic `semop` function right after `semget`. And if this is really the first process, the extension assigns `SYSVSEM_SEM` semaphore value to `$max_acquire`.

*Semaphore 1 a.k.a. `SYSVSEM_USAGE`*

The number of processes using the semaphore.

*Semaphore 2 a.k.a. `SYSVSEM_SETVAL`*

Plays a role of a lock for internal `SETVAL` and `GETVAL` operations (see `man 2 semctl`). For example, it is set to `1` while the extension sets `SYSVSEM_SEM` to `$max_acquire`, then is reset back to zero.

Finally, `sem_get` wraps a structure (containing the semaphore set ID, key and other information) into a PHP resource and returns it.

So you should call it in some initialization process, when you're only preparing to work with semaphores.

### `sem_acquire()`

This is where the `$max_acquire` [goes into play](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/16160386982a86e6ec7969c6c89707d38228f19e/ext/sysvsem/sysvsem.c#L330).

`SYSVSEM_SEM`'s value (let's call it `semval`) is initially equal to `$max_acquire`. `semop()` blocks until `semval` becomes greater than or equal to `1`. Then `1` is substracted from `semval`.

If `$max_acquire = 1`, then `semval` becomes zero after the first call, and the next calls to `sem_acquire()` will block until `semval` is restored by `sem_release()` call.

Call it when you need to acquire the next "lock" from the available set (`$max_acquire`).

### `sem_release()`

Does pretty much the same as `sem_acquire()`, except it increments `SYSVSEM_SEM`'s value.

Call it when you need to no longer need the "lock" acquired previously with `sem_acquire()`.

### `sem_remove()`

Immediately removes the semaphore set, awakening allprocesses blocked in `semop` on the set (from `IPC_RMID` section, *SEMCTL(2)* man page).

So this is effectively the same as removing a semaphore with `ipcrm` command.

Answer (score 0):

The file permissions should be **0666** instead of **6000** for what you're trying to do.

Comment: The first argument is not permissions, but the semaphore ID.