# PHP sem_get function fails

Tags: php, semaphore, sysv-ipc

I have implemented an access control for insertions into a database table that is used for a reservation service. It works fine for some time, then the `sem_get()` function fails despite the fact that I call `sem_release()` after every `sem_get()`.

```
case 'room':
    $key = "room";
    $semaphore = sem_get($key, 1, 0666, 1);
    if ($semaphore) {
        sem_acquire($semaphore);
        //do some stuff
        if ($already_reserved_rooms < $max_rooms) {
            $return="ok";
            sem_release($semaphore);
            return $return;
        }
          sem_release($semaphore);
    }
    else {
      //send me mail that semaphore failed 
    }

    return 'no rooms';
    break;
```

Should I call `sem_remove()` as well?

I followed steps on [this](http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-semaphores) site.

Comment: When `sem_get` fails, it logs a warning. Show us the warning.

Comment: I'd say from the description of `sem_remove` it's definitely not something you want to be doing before you're completely done with that semaphore in **all** processes.

Comment: thanks sir for reply ,this all what i can found PHP Warning:  sem_release(): SysV semaphore 5 (key 0x214) is not currently acquired

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you just lock the database table instead of using a semaphore?

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for your comment , because there is a lot of cases in this table and i want to lock based on each one not on entire table .

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov please see my log above

Comment: @drupaler1, where? Have you updated the question? I don't see any logs here.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov it seem that it fails in step  sem_get for no reason

Comment: @drupaler1, everything has a reason, and [`sem_get`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/16160386982a86e6ec7969c6c89707d38228f19e/ext/sysvsem/sysvsem.c#L189) logs a warning in case of failure. So please show the logs.

Answer (score 3):

**Removing Semaphores**

Yes, you should call `sem_remove()` when you are done with the semaphore set. Otherwise, the semaphore set will persist in the system until you remove it. However, the fact that the semaphore set persists causes *no problem* while the number of semaphores is less than the `SEMMNS` limit:

> `SEMMNS` System-wide limit on the number of semaphores: policy dependent (on Linux, this limit can be read and modified via the second field of  `/proc/sys/kernel/sem`).

`sem_remove()` immediately removes the semaphore set awakening all processes blocked using this semaphore.

By the way, you can use the `ipcrm` command to remove semaphores from command line, and the `ipcs` command to show information on IPC facilities (including semaphores).

**Releasing Semaphores**

You are not required to call `sem_release()` while the auto-release flag (`sem_get`'s 4th parameter) is on. But it is a good idea to release semaphores as long as you don't need the acquired "lock".

`sem_release()` only increments the value of internal semaphore. Think of it as an unlocking operation, the opposite of `sem_acquire()`.

**`sem_get()` Failures**

The [`sem_get()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/16160386982a86e6ec7969c6c89707d38228f19e/ext/sysvsem/sysvsem.c#L189) function returns `FALSE` in the following cases

- PHP parameter parsing failure (`E_ERROR`);
- semaphore exists, but the calling process does not have permission to access the set (`E_WARNING`);
- memory allocation error (`E_WARNING`);
- the maximum number of semaphore sets, or the system wide maximum number of semaphores exceeds (`E_WARNING`)

In each of the cases `sem_get` logs an error, or a warning. So you *have to check the logs* in order to find out the root of the problem.

Since your code works for some time, it is not parameter parsing issue, and not the permissions. Memory allocation issues are rare. So it is very likely that you are running out of the semaphore number limits. Check out the man page for `semget` for reference. The man page describes how to read and modify the limits via `/proc/sys/kernel/sem`.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976805/how-to-properly-use-php5-semaphores/39980215#39980215) answer for more information regarding the `sysvsem` extension internals.

Comment: thanks sir for your comment ,but what is the difference between it and sem_release? and then how i will control semaphore for other users as i want them all to share same semaphore.

Comment: when you are saying "when you are done " you mean at the end of the above case in my code , if i called sem_remove() at the end of the case will it effect the other processes that waiting for the one who currently acquiring the semaphore to release ?

Comment: @drupaler1, `sem_release` unlocks a semaphore, `sem_remove` removes a semaphore set. You can leave the semaphore set persistent, but it would be less error-prone to remove it somewhere near the request shutdown phase. By _done with a semaphore set_ I mean the point when you no longer need to perform any operations on the semaphore set. `sem_acquire` blocks until the semaphore can be acquired. As long as the semaphore set exists, you can acquire/release freely. You _are not required to remove_ the sem.set. See the updated answer.

Comment: sorry for late reply ,but i have used ipcs and ipcrm and removed all the old semaphores ,and uploaded the new code again ,it works fine for about 20 hour and failed again to get semaphore . log now contains those two llines repeated :

`sem_get(): failed for key 0x20e: No space left on device`

`sem_remove() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Comment: @drupaler1, it's `ENOSPC` error, which means that the system limit for the maximum number  of  semaphore sets (`SEMMNI`), or the system wide maximum number of semaphores (`SEMMNS`) exceeded. `SEMMNI` is the 4th field of `/proc/sys/kernel/sem`, `SEMMNS` is the 2nd field. Check how many semaphores do you have with `ipcs`

Comment: @drupaler1, obviously, you should reduce the number of different keys

Comment: guess i will have 1200 different semaphore is that acceptable ?

Comment: @drupaler1, as I said, check your `/proc/sys/kernel/sem`. The 2nd field is system-wide  limit on the number of semaphores, the 4th - system-wide limit on the number of semaphore sets. `sem_get` creates a set of 3 semaphores.

Answer (score 2):

the `sem_get` function returns false in your case, because you give a string instead of integer.

Replace

```
$semaphore = sem_get($key, 1, 0666, 1);
```

by

```
$semaphore = sem_get(crc32($key), 1, 0666, 1);
```

It will work

Answer (score 1):

The $key argument for sem_get() is integer, while you are passing it as string. Please consider getting the integer key by the ftok() call.

So please consider replacing

```
$key = "room";
```

to the following code:

```
$project = "r"; // Project identifier. This must be a one character string.
$key = ftok(__FILE__, $project);
```